# Could not calculate upgrade when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. Can't find solution that works

Tags: apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I finally decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 today after waiting to ensure there was compatibility with some programs I use my Ubuntu machine for. While running the upgrade today I got an error saying:

> Could not calculate the upgrade
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu->release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in >'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at >'main.log' and 'apt.log'."

I've searched tirelessly through forums and anywhere I could find help with this subject, and tried a few solutions I found, but none seem to fit my circumstance. I've disabled all unofficial and third-party packages that I know of.  I wanted to see if someone could take a look at my logs from /var/log/dist-upgrade/ and help me with a solution to this error. I would really appreciate any help anyone could give me.

Links to log files-

[apt.log](https://pastebin.com/Y60ZCLT7)

[main.log](https://pastebin.com/8ZXYf8GV)

Answer (score 0):

From the apt.log it seems like most of the issues relate to python2, python3, etc.

Would you be willing to

```
    sudo apt remove python2
    sudo apt remove python3
```

then retry your upgrade?

If that succeeds, you may replace the packages that you need.

Make sure you capture the list of removals so that you can reinstall when you hit 20.04

avoid running

```
    sudo apt purge
```

though.

Regards,
mondotofu